# Installing Lua 5.2.1 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: lua

I tried to use the following command:

```
curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.0.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.2.0.tar.gz
cd lua-5.2.0
make macosx test install
```

(But with 5.2.1 obviously)

But it says it doesn't know the command `make`.

Comment: You may want to get a ready-made binary from http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [install XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12) in order to have the `make` command.
Then go to: Preferences and then Downloads and install a component named "Command Line Tools".
Finally run `Install Xcode.app` from your Applications folder.